# Maintaining proper Activity scope with Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gesture

I am having troubles organizing my Java classes so that the scope of everything I need to access in any given object is available.

For example, I have a MainActivity that has a ListView that I want to attach an onFling gesture listener to in order to remove ListView items when they are swiped off the screen. However, I cannot figure out how to set up the listener so that the Listener has access to my ArrayAdapter and ListView as well as is accessible by the MainActivity for instantiating it onCreate().

What is the correct way to set this up?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements onSelectionMade {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    private static View current;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    @Override
    public void doChange(int val){
        if(val == onSelectionMade.OK){
            // Add contact
            current.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(60, 242, 102));

        }else if(val == onSelectionMade.CANCEL){
            current.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(237, 47, 47));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR BECAUSE MyGestureListener IS NOT IN THE                         SCOPE OF THE MAIN ACTIVITY
        this.mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        ContactAdapter adapter;
        ListView view;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            Contact contactList[] = new Contact[] 
            {
                    new Contact("Matt", "Hintzke", "2062259311", "matt.hintzke@email.wsu.edu"),
                    new Contact("John", "Smith", "2062236457", "john@email.com"),
                    new Contact("Bob", "Harrison", "2064318756", "bob@email.com"),
                    new Contact("Colleen", "Arnold", "2065553696", "ween@email.com"),
                    new Contact("Harry", "Larkin", "3608785423", "poop@gmail.com")
            };

            adapter = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contact_item , contactList);   

            view = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            view.setAdapter(adapter);

            view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id){

                    Contact item = (Contact) parentAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    current = view;
                    //adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));

                    DialogFragment dialog = AddContactDialog.newInstance(item);

                    dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Add Contact Dialog");
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), item.first, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


            return rootView;
        }


        class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
            private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures"; 


            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
                    float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                if(event2.getX() - event1.getX() > 10){
                    int id = view.pointToPosition((int) event1.getX(), (int) event1.getY());
                    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(id));
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

    }







}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way would be, I think, to place object declarations in the "smallest" scope that needs them.

For example, in this case, both the `ListView` and its `GestureDetector` should be inside the `Fragment`. The Activity should not be concerned about them (e.g. fragments should be replaceable -- if you replaced then Fragment with another one that *doesn't* have a ListView, why would you need the GestureDetector)?

The same goes for the implementor of the `OnSelectionMade` interface, &c.

Also, the fragment doesn't need to be an inner class of the Activity. I'm not sure why the IDE creates them like this, it leads to confusion :/

Comment: The way you worded this really helped me get a grasp on scoping within Android programming across the board.  Great answer!